# What's the replacement for Oracle.Connection?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, deprecated

I have a vb.net program that is failing, but giving no errors.  I've just discovered that the code I am using is deprecated. But what is the replacment?  (That seems like something useful for MSDN to list, but I'm sure not seeing it.)

```
Private Sub SetConnectionToDB(ByRef oCMD As OracleCommand)
    Dim connectionString As String
    connectionString = My.Settings.ImportDataConnectionString
    Dim OraDBConnection As OracleConnection
    OraDBConnection = New OracleConnection(connectionString)

    oCMD.Connection = OraDBConnection
    oCMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.aspx)  states that

> This type is deprecated and will be
>   removed in a future version of the
>   .NET Framework. For more information,
>   see Oracle and ADO.NET.

[Oracle and ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7.aspx) states

> The types in System.Data.OracleClient
>   are deprecated. The types are
>   supported in version 4 of the .NET
>   Framework but will be removed in a
>   future release. Microsoft recommends
>   that you use a third-party Oracle
>   provider.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone needs this spelled out, here are the steps I created for another developer (we are developing using C#, not vb.net).  Note that this was an easy migration.

The Oracle guide: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/getstarted-c/getstarted_c_otn.htm.

I created/followed these steps:

Link to download Oracle Developer Tools: http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html.  (You might need to create an account).  Then click “Downloads” and download “32-bit ODAC with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio Downloads” (obviously click the “64-bit…” link if needed)

That downloads: \Downloads\ODTwithODAC121021.zip.

Open the Zip and copy the contents to any location. (has a setup.exe)

Run the “setup.exe”

Installation instructions (if needed): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/install121021-2389380.html

When installing I used all default values.

Note: Installation hung at 64% (…spawning…exe…) but it did eventually continue on its own.

I copied for reference their note presented when the install completed.  Starts with "Run the SQL scripts located in..."

In your class where data access occurs, add:
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;

You’ll get: “The type or namespace ‘Oracle’ could not be found (are you missing a directive or assembly reference?)”

Right click the project: Add/reference: Assemblies/Extensions: Oracle.DataAccess Version 4.121.2.0

Comment out the existing: //using System.Data.OracleClient; (Or else you’ll get an “OracleConnection is an ambiguous reference” error.)

I didn't even need to modify my existing code, e.g.:

Conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked (and answered) a long time ago, but in case anyone else is just discovering this, I personally recommend using [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html).